# In Fedora, how do I select a proper Norwegian keyboard layout?

Tags: fedora, keyboard-layout, i18n, input-method

I just installed Fedora 19 in VirtualBox using [an image from virtualboxes.org](http://virtualboxes.org/images/fedora/#fedora19).

However, I'm unable to select a proper Norwegian keyboard.  When I open the keyboard layout, it shows an US layout.  A [Norwegian layout should have Æ, Ø, Å keys](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/c/c9/Keyboard_Layout_Norwegian.png) and a lot of other stuff.

[image: Keyboard Layout]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I figured it out eventually:

- `yum install system-config-keyboard`
- Run `system-config-keyboard` as root
- Select Norsk (aka Norwegian)

Now the correct keyboard layout shows up in the Settings GUI.

Answer (score 12):

There are a methods to do this. After installing the keyboard configuration package:

```
$ sudo yum install system-config-keyboard
...
Installed:
  system-config-keyboard.x86_64 0:1.3.1-14.fc19

Dependency Installed:
  system-config-keyboard-base.x86_64 0:1.3.1-14.fc19
```

2 packages will get installed.

#### Method #1

From here you can then invoke `system-config-keyboard` directly:

[image: ss of dialog #1]

#### Method #2

Via the command tool `setup`.

```
$ sudo setup
[sudo] password for saml:
```

[image: ss of dialog #2]

Selecting Keyboard configuration will take you to the keyboard configuration (same as above).

#### Method #3

Through the GNOME 3 settings you can also change the keyboard like so.

Open up *Settings* and select *Keyboard*:

[image: dialog #1]

Select *Input Sources*:

[image: dialog #2]

Select the plus (`+`), to add a new source:

[image: dialog #3]

Type the name of the layout you want, in your case it's "Nor..".

[image: dialog #4]

#### Method #4

Via the command line you can also change the keyboard layout using the tool `localectl`. To get a list of keyboard layouts, use the switch `list-keymaps`. This method was found here on the ask.fedoraprojects.org site, titled: [Change default system keyboard layout for virtual console.](https://ask.fedoraproject.org/question/31659/change-default-system-keyboard-layout-for-virtual-console/).

#### Example

```
$ localectl list-keymaps
ANSI-dvorak
af-fa-olpc
af-olpc-ps
af-ps
af-uz
af-uz-olpc
am-eastern
...
```

Once you've identified the layout you want.

- change console keymap: `localectl set-keymap jp106`
- change x11 keymap: `localectl set-x11-keymap jp`

**NOTE:** The set-x11-keymap options are much more flexible, see the manpage for instructions on listing the available parameters.

Comment: Method #3 was the one I tried first, as you can see on my screenshot.  Didn't work.

Comment: @neu242 - OK, these are the methods that I've seen used in the past, I was capturing them here as a single spot, since they're fractured all over the internet. Was there any additional info w/ #3 that would show why it didn't work? Perhaps running that applet from a terminal window would show an error message?

Comment: No error messages, it just showed the US layout.  It seems to depend on system-config-keyboard, then it worked as it should.

Comment: @neu242 - seems strange to me, that that GUI doesn't appear to have any effect on the settings. Oh well.