# Fedora 20 kde change keyboard layout permantely to Latin America?

Tags: fedora, keyboard-layout

I'm trying to change it to Latin America language, however in the System Settings->Hardaware->input devices-layout tab nothing seem to works correctly (even if I add any layout)

[image]

Also I can type for accents but in a weird manner. I have used the answer as discussed 
[here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/104217/in-fedora-how-do-i-select-a-proper-norwegian-keyboard-layout). I have used that answer (the method # 1 and # 2) `system-config-keyboard` selecting Latin America, and works perfect but when I restart the computer changes are not saved, and need to do that again.

[image]

What can I do then?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you trying as a root user? Open the command prompt and type,

```
system-config-language
```

After selecting the language you want, the next time you boot, the settings will take place. To verify if the language change took place, run the below command.

```
locale
```

However, since you want to change the keyboard layout, you can use the command,

```
system-config-keyboard
```

After changing the keyboard configuration, you can verify if the change took place by using the below command.

```
setxkbmap -print | grep xkb_symbols | awk '{print $4}' | awk -F"+" '{print $2}'
```